# AcceptedAtAction with forward slash

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to properly return AcceptedAtAction ActionResult at the end of a Web API method in .NET 5.

I need to pass an URI with the location at which the status of requested content can be monitored, in the form like http://localhost/controller/token/status

I can do everything except that the last forward slash is encoded as %2f, so I get something like http://localhost/mycontroller/3f87baec-24af-4def-8768-b006110e1243%2Fstatus

```
return AcceptedAtAction($"{newGuid}/status");
```

I tried to encode the token to base64 string, but it seems to have no influence.

How can I make make a forward slash be sent back?

UPDATE:
Method signature:

```
[HttpPost("api/thiscontroller")]
public async Task<ActionResult> PostMethod(Dummy dummy)
```

Comment: Do you have a controller and action method mapped to that URL? Can you share the signature of the action method?

Comment: The controller and action are fine I guess. Method is properly called. My problem is that the resulting string from $"{newGuid}/status" contains %2f instead a forward slash. As mentioned in the question, it returns http://localhost/mycontroller/3f87baec-24af-4def-8768-b006110e1243%2Fstatus. Everything is correct but the last forward slash.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.acceptedataction?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Thank for the link. Actually I am using it already to find my way, but with all overloads I always end up with forward slash replaced by %2f on the location response header. Interesting is that this response format seems standard, as mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design#conform-to-http-semantics